# How to show all versions of a library from specified repo?

Tags: yum, rpm

I thought I've uploaded a rpm with version `myserv-2-7.rpm` to a custom repo `myrepo1`, but when I use:

```
yum --enablerepo myrepo1 install myserv
```

It installed a different version of `myserv` from another repo.

I want to identify the problem, but don't know how to do it.

How to use `yum` to view the existing versions of a lib from specified repo?

I just want to know in repo `myrepo1`, is there any `myserv`, and what're the versions are they if there are.

Answer (score 10):

Finally found the answer:

1. show all versions of a lib:

   ```
   yum list available gcc --showduplicates
   ```
2. show specified repo only

   ```
   yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="google" list available gcc --showduplicates
   ```